# Как сделать заголовок уникальным?

Tags: предложение

Я заметил: чтобы избежать повторения, к заголовкам добавляют цифры (в разных скобках и без них) или инициалы. Предлагаю согласовать единый подход и придерживаться его по мере возможности. Наиболее естественно, на мой взгляд, добавлять порядковый номер в круглых скобках, при этом начинать с номера 2:

- Вопрос
- Вопрос (2)
- Вопрос (3) и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Запрет идентичных заголовков введён не просто так. Если заголовок уже был использован, то велика вероятность, что и суть вопроса та же, что была у предыдущего. В таком случае потребность задавать его отпадает. Если уже существуют вопросы с заголовками, которые отличаются лишь такими индексами, и при этом их суть идентична, то наиболее правильный вариант - объединить их в один (более серьёзная операция нежели отметка в качестве дубликата). Если же суть отличается - хорошо бы её отразить в заголовке (ведь он для того и нужен, чтобы отражать суть), т.е. исправить его без необходимости использовать числа порядковых номеров.

Comment: Дело в том, что на нашем сайте задается немало вопросов, связанных с пунктуацией. Все они более или менее типовые, и назвать каждый из них по-особенному — невозможно. Таким образом, нам такой запрет только вредит.

Comment: @Aer здесь хорошо бы иметь пример списка подобных вопросов, чтобы понимать, что одинаковых заголовков нельзя избежать. То есть, что подходы из моего ответа не работоспособны.

Comment: Пожалуйста: https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%5B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%09is%3Aquestion. Обратите внимание на то, сколько там просто иносказательных заголовков.

Comment: @Aer у Вас довольно широкий разброс, предлагаю локализовать поиск, получится [не так много](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=Title%3A%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%22+%5B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+is%3Aquestion). И, я думаю, здесь можно навести порядок, т.е. сделать заголовки более говорящими и уникальными.

Comment: Вы взяли за основу лишь один вариант заголовка, а я неслучайно дал ссылку на вопросы со всем многообразием... Может, вы и правы, но в некоторых случаях без такого общего заголовка, увы, тяжело.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что предложенный вами подход довольно-таки неплох. Интересно, что думают другие участники.